# Uploaded images to cloudinary saves the images three times in my cloud storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please i am facing this problem with my configuration on uploading images to my cloud storage(Cloudinary).
when i upload a single image in my rails app, it makes a duplicated of times 3 in my cloud storage.

I am Using ruby 2.3 & Rails 5.1 with paperclip-cloudinary ~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.2

I am pretty sure is the path that i set.
i dont know how to set the right path.

```
:path => ':class/:id/:style/:filename'
```

### My Post Model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments

    has_attached_file :image, 
    :storage => :cloudinary,
    :path => ':class/:id/:style/:filename',
    styles: { medium: "700x500#", small: "350x250>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Comment: I probably save the image resized to 700x500, to 2350x250 and the original version.  What is wrong with that?

Comment: @spickermann please thats not the question i asked. My problem is, when i upload a single image from my rails app to the cloud, the image appears 3 in my cloudinary storage. I mean it becomes triplet

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the :style  in the path

```
:path => ':class/:id/:style/:filename'
```

to prevent making duplicate of the styles defined, remove the style option from the path

for it to be like this =>

```
:path => ':class/:id/:filename'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a  duplicate image. It's a three images of different dimensions that you are mentioning in styles.

1st one is your original image that you are actually uploading.

Second and third will be of medium: "700x500#", small: "350x250 respectively.

You can call other two's are thumbnails of the original image.